# PowerShell -Confirm only once per function call

Tags: powershell

I'm obviously trying to do something wrong, so hoping someone can help since it seems easy and it is probably an easy mistake. Basically I am writing a little script to create new folders and I want to include `-Confirm`, but I want it to basically ask ONCE if the user wants to continue, instead of asking for each nested folder that is created.

Here's what I have so far

```
function Create-NewFolderStructure{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$NewFolderName,
    
    [Parameter()]
    $LiteralPath = (Get-Location),

    [Parameter()]
    $inputFile = "zChildDirectoryNames.txt"
)
process {
$here = $LiteralPath
$directories = Get-Content -LiteralPath "$($here)\$($inputFile)"
If (-not (Test-Path -Path "$($here)\$($NewFolderName)")){
    $directories | ForEach-Object {New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path "$($here)\$($NewFolderName)" -Name $_}
}
Else {
    Write-Host "A $($NewFolderName) folder already exists"
}
}
end {
}
}
```

The issue is that if I use `-Confirm` when calling my function, or directly at `New-Item` - I end up getting the confirmation prompt for every single 'child folder' that is being created. Even with the first prompt, saying "Yes to all" doesn't suppress future prompts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69272203/45375) provides an *alternative* to using the [common `-Confirm` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-confirm), via a slightly different mechanism based on a custom `-Force` switch that inverts the logic of your own attempt (prompt is shown by default, can be skipped with `-Force`).

If you want **to make your `-Confirm`-based approach work**:

- Call [`.ShouldProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ShouldProcess) *yourself* at the start of the `process` block, which presents the familiar confirmation prompt, ...
- ... and, if the method returns `$true` - indicating that the use confirmed - perform the desired operations *after setting a local copy of the [`$ConfirmPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#confirmpreference) to `'None'`*, so as to prevent the cmdlets involved in your operations to each prompt *as well*.

```sh
function New-FolderStructure {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string] $NewFolderName,      
    [string] $LiteralPath = $PWD,  
    [string] $InputFile = "zChildDirectoryNames.txt"
  )

  # This block is called once, before pipeline processing begins.
  begin {
    $directories = Get-Content -LiteralPath "$LiteralPath\$InputFile"
  }

  # This block is called once if parameter $NewFolderName is bound
  # by an *argument* and once for each input string if bound via the *pipeline*.
  process {

    # If -Confirm was passed, this will prompt for confirmation
    # and return `$true` if the user confirms.
    # Otherwise `$true` is automatically returned, which also happens
    # if '[A] Yes to All' was chosen for a previous input string.
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($NewFolderName)) {

      # Prevent the cmdlets called below from *also* prompting for confirmation.
      # Note: This creates a *local copy* of the $ConfirmPreference
      # preference variable.
      $ConfirmPreference = 'None'

      If (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath "$LiteralPath\$NewFolderName")) {
        $directories | ForEach-Object { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$LiteralPath\$NewFolderName" -Name $_ }
      }
      Else {
        Write-Host "A $NewFolderName folder already exists"
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Note:

- I've changed your function's name from `Create-NewFolderStructure` to `New-FolderStructure` to comply with PowerShell's naming conventions, using the [approved "verb"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) `New` and streamlined the code in a number of ways.
- `ValueFromPipeline` was added as a property to the `$NewFolderName` parameter so as to support passing *multiple* values via the pipeline (e.g.
  `'foo', 'bar' | New-FolderStructure -Confirm`)

  - Note that the `process` block is then called *for each input string*, and will also prompt for each, unless you respond with `[A] Yes to All`); PowerShell remembers this choice between `process` calls and makes `.ShouldProcess()` automatically return `$true` in subsequent calls; similarly, responding to `[L] No to All` automatically returns `$false` in subsequent calls.
- The need to set `$ConfirmPreference` to `'None'` stems from the fact that **PowerShell automatically translates the caller's  use of `-Confirm` into a function-local `$ConfirmPreference` variable with value `'Low'`**, which makes all cmdlets that support `-Confirm` act as if `-Confirm` had been passed.

  - `.ShouldProcess()` does *not* pick up in-function changes to the value of this `$ConfirmPreference` copy, so it is OK to set it to `'None'`, without affecting the prompt logic of subsequent `process` invocations.

Comment: I get the feeling adding `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` is something I missed initially as I couldn't get the confirmation to fire when I set the `ConfirmImpact` to `'High'` within the `CmdleBinding` itself. I've already rewritten it quite a bit and added the `ValueFromPipeline` myself, but I'm a tiny bit stuck on whether I need an `End{}` block or not. I moved the `$here` and `$directory` variables into `Begin{}`, but should I create the actual directories within the `Process` block, or should I just collect the piped Names into a list and then take action on that entire list in the `End` block?

Comment: On a related question - but does setting the `$ConfirmPreference` mean that you only have a single `ShouldProcess()` call sent to the user? Now that I'm looking at my updated code, it is more similar to how @Mathias set it up...except I created my own copy of a `Write-PromptHost` Cmdlet vs. using `$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue`. Either way, it does seem like this method requires a different mechanism if there are two (or more) `ShouldProcess` 'things' taking place

Comment: @immobile2, in general, only wait until the `end` block is called if you truly _must_ collect all input first (as `Sort-Object` has to, for instance) - otherwise, act on each input object individually in `process`.  Please see my update, which streamlines the code, including moving the `Get-Content` call to the `begin` block, as you suggested.

Comment: @immobile2, as for `$ConfirmPreference`: No, as explained in the answer, setting `$ConfirmPreference` has the desired effect on the cmdlets inside the `if` block, but doesn't affect the behavior of `.ShouldProcess()`, whose logic is _locked in beforehand_.

Answer (score 2):

In order to consume the user's answer to the confirmation prompt, you have to *actually ask them*!

You can do so by calling `$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue()`:

```
function Create-NewFolderStructure {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$NewFolderName,
        
        [Parameter()]
        $LiteralPath = (Get-Location),
    
        [Parameter()]
        $inputFile = "zChildDirectoryNames.txt",

        [switch]$Force
    )

    process {
        if(-not $Force){
            $yesToAll = $false
            $noToAll = $false
            if($PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue("Do you want to go ahead and create new directory '${NewFolderName}'?", "Danger!", [ref]$yesToAll, [ref]$noToAll)){
                if($yesToAll){
                    $Force = $true
                }
            }
            else{
                return
            }
        }

        # Replace with actual directory creation logic here, 
        # pass `-Force` or `-Confirm:$false` to New-Item to suppress its own confirmation prompt
        Write-Host "Creating new folder ${NewFolderName}" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Now, if the user presses `[A]` ("Yes To All"), we'll remember it by setting `$Force` to true, which will skip any subsequent calls to `ShouldContinue()`:

```
PS ~> "folder 1","folder 2"|Create-NewFolderStructure

Danger!
Do you want to go ahead and create new directory 'folder 1'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): A
Creating new folder folder 1
Creating new folder folder 2
PS ~>
```

I'd strongly suggest reading through this deep dive to better understand the `SupportsShouldProcess` facility: [Everything you wanted to know about ShouldProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess)

Comment: Thanks! I did take a look at the linked document before posing the question, but I think I skipped the `ShouldContinue()` section as I was trying to conquer the aspects of `-Confirm`, and `ConfirmImpact = 'High'`. It seems like this solution doesn't require the `CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)` though and you end up needing to write a lot of new code just to display the 'correct' message and get the return values back from the user based on their choice

Comment: Mathias - How would you implement handling the `No to All` selection with this method? The link you sent doesn't seem to cover it, but their `If` block would be `If ($Force -or ShouldContinue() then do things`. So I'm guessing that `ShouldContinue()` will know Yes/No to All, but we're still using `$Force` when the answer is Yes to All. Does there need to be a `NotForce` equivalent?